# Python Extracting nested values from a json string using pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Below is a nested json I am using:

```
{
    "9": {
        "uid": "9",
        "name": "pedro",
        "mail": "pedro@pedro.com",
        "roles": [
            "authenticated",
            "administrator"
        ],
        "user_status": "1"
    },
    "10": {
        "uid": "10",
        "name": "Rosa",
        "mail": "rosa@rosa.com",
        "roles": [
            "authenticated",
            "administrator"
        ],
        "user_status": "1"
    },
    "11": {
        "uid": "11",
        "name": "Tania",
        "mail": "tania@tania.com",
        "roles": [
            "authenticated",
            "administrator"
        ],
        "user_status": "1"
    }
}
```

Each first key is different from the rest. I need to extract the information between each of the keys, e.g. uid, name, mail, etc but not interested on the key id (9,10,11). Is there any way to achieve this without passing the key id on the code?

Below is what I’ve attempted thus far:

```
import json

outputuids = {
        "9": {
            "uid": "9",
            "name": "pedro",
            "mail": "pedro@pedro.com",
            "roles": [
                "authenticated",
                "administrator"
            ],
            "user_status": "1"
        },
        "10": {
            "uid": "10",
            "name": "Rosa",
            "mail": "rosa@rosa.com",
            "roles": [
                "authenticated",
                "administrator"
            ],
            "user_status": "1"
        },
        "11": {
            "uid": "11",
            "name": "Tania",
            "mail": "tania@tania.com",
            "roles": [
                "authenticated",
                "administrator"
            ],
            "user_status": "1"
        }
    }

    data1 = json.loads(outputuids)
    for i in data1:
       fuid=data1['9']['uid']
       fname=data1['9']['name']
       print (fuid + fname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is overkill for this task. You can iterate over `outputuids.values()` to avoid having to explicitly refer to the keys of the dictionary:

```py
result = []
keys_to_retain = {"uid", "name", "mail"}

for val in outputuids.values():
    result.append({k: v for k, v in val.items() if k in keys_to_retain})

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 {'uid': '9', 'name': 'pedro', 'mail': 'pedro@pedro.com'},
 {'uid': '10', 'name': 'Rosa', 'mail': 'rosa@rosa.com'},
 {'uid': '11', 'name': 'Tania', 'mail': 'tania@tania.com'}
]
```